# Webview Session Storage lost when navigate between Xamarin pages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms App with Two Pages, one with a WebView and other with just text.

Session Storage lost data when I navigate between pages.

//APage.xaml

```
<WebView x:Name="webView" WidthRequest="1000" HeightRequest="1000" Navigated="webView_Navigated">
  <WebView.Source>
    <UrlWebViewSource />
  </WebView.Source>
</WebView>
```

//BPage.xaml

```
<Span Text="Hi B Page"/>
```

//APage.xaml.cs

```
...

 public BPage()
  {
            InitializeComponent();

            (webView.Source as UrlWebViewSource).Url = "mytestsite.com";

  }

private async void webView_Navigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
  {
            var webView = sender as WebView;
          
            var token = await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("window.sessionStorage.getItem('token')");

            System.Console.WriteLine(token); //Every time I Go to BPage and back, it is null.
  }
```

My website return a "Token not found in sessionstorage" error.

Answer (score 1):

> //Every time I Go to B Page and back, it is null.

When you `navigate from B to A`, page B will be **released** and every time you `navigate from A to B`, you are navigating to a **new PageB**(not the same PageB every time).

Each webView you use is under different Page B and that's why you get null.

Here is the document about [Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical).

You can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) to save token in apps.

Save:

```
Preferences.Set("my_key", "my_value");
```

Read:

```
var myValue = Preferences.Get("my_key", "default_value");
```

Comment: When I navigate, I use, AppShell.xaml  or `Shell.Current.GoToAsync`. 
Then it not instantiate a new Page. It use the same page. (break point in the constructor just stop one time.

I found a issue in github that indicate it is a bug in https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9073

Comment: Preferences.Set dont works, because sessionstorage stay inside webview.

Comment: Does the token change every time? You can get the token and store it with Preferences.Set when you leave the page.

Comment: How can I set the token in webview?
I believe with javascript, but this does not to seem to be  the right way to do it.

in addition to token has others data in session storage, like refresh token, claims, username, license, etc.

Xamarin should not delete the sessionstorage when i navigate between pages.

Comment: Your case is different from the problem in the issue link if you navigate between pages. Navigating to a new PageB probably is creating a new page instead of using the old page. Are you testing in Android or iOS?

Comment: I am testing in Android.
The page is not new, I doble check it.
Just the prop "Source" in webview change the instance (I use Console.WriteLine(webview.GetHashCode()) and Console.WriteLine(webview.Source.GetHashCode())  to compare).

Comment: Ok, you can raise an issue in Github if you can confirm that.